# How can I decode json in PHP 5.1?

Tags: php, json, parsing

json_decode function is not part of PHP 5.1, so I cannot use it. Is there any other function for this version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before PHP 5.2, you can use the [JSON PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/json).

In fact, it is the extension that has been integrated into PHP 5.2 *([quoting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.requirements.php))* :

> As of PHP 5.2.0, the JSON extension is
> bundled and compiled into PHP by
> default.

Some other solutions would be to use some component developped in PHP.

Some time ago (about one year ago), I used the [`Zend_Json` component of Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.html), with PHP 5.1.

Even if Zend Framework requires PHP 5.2, that component can be extracted *(I think it depends only on one other component -- maybe `Zend_Exception`, or something like that)* -- and one year ago, it was possible to use it with PHP 5.1.

The [official JSON website][4] also links to several PHP-based or PHP-oriented components -- you might want to take a look at that list.

Comment: Thanx, how can I install that, it has no documentation of that, it only links to php site that says there is no need to install it because it is part of php lol

Comment: Installing a PECL extension, at least on a Linux system, is generally quite simple : `pecl install json` ; note that you might need some "dev" packages from your distribution ;;; Might also be interesting to take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php

Comment: If you need to alter the default php5-json, try [Package php5-json breaks firephp](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87067/package-php5-json-breaks-firephp).

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue running PHP 5.1.6, but I couldn't upgrade or install extensions on my client's server. To make matters worse, the JSON.org site was down when I needed a solution but fortunately this file on Google Code worked perfectly! I would have preferred to actually define json_encode/json_decode, but calling fromJSON() worked just fine.

http://code.google.com/p/simplejson-php/

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. In fairness I can't blame the author of simplejson.php for naming his functions differently, as their signatures don't match those of the builtins. I *can*, however, blame him for `eval()`ing the JSON string once constructed!

Answer (score 3):

You're seeing this error because you have a php version earlier than 5.2.0.  These functions are [included by default](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.requirements.php) in php 5.2.0 and later.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function json_encode()
```

You can [install](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php) the [PECL extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) by running:

```
pecl install json
```

It will compile, then add this to your `php.ini` file: (mine is in `/etc/php5/apache2`)

```
extension=json.so
```

Then restart apache.

Answer (score 1):

In my server i can't install JSON PECL extension, because it causes a problem with zend_json that is used in another app. So i found this script that works perfectly.

**jsonwrapper: json_encode for earlier versions of PHP 5.x**

PHP 5.2 adds the `json_encode` function, which turns almost any PHP data structure into valid JavaScript code. Hashes, arrays, arrays of hashes, whatever.

Unfortunately a lot of Linux distributions are still shipping with PHP 5.1.x.

jsonwrapper implements the `json_encode` function if it is missing, and leaves it alone if it is already present. ***So it is nicely future-compatible.***

Just add:

```
require 'jsonwrapper.php';
```

http://www.boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html

Answer (score 0):

The Zend framework has Zend_Json. At least it used to a couple of years ago.

http://framework.zend.com/download

You can just pull out the JSON library and use it in a standalone manner.

Comment: Not sure why whoever -1'd me did so. While this isn't perhaps as good as the PECL solution, it's still a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

#### code

```
<?php 
if ( !function_exists('json_decode') ){ 
function json_decode($json) 
{  
    // Author: walidator.info 2009 
    $comment = false; 
    $out = '$x='; 

    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($json); $i++) 
    { 
        if (!$comment) 
        { 
            if ($json[$i] == '{' || $json[$i] == '[')        $out .= ' array('; 
            else if ($json[$i] == '}' || $json[$i] == ']')    $out .= ')'; 
            else if ($json[$i] == ':')    $out .= '=>'; 
            else                         $out .= $json[$i];            
        } 
        else $out .= $json[$i]; 
        if ($json[$i] == '"')    $comment = !$comment; 
    } 
    eval($out . ';'); 
    return $x; 
}  
} 
?>
```

#### warning

this is untested, I found it on the internet

#### link

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#91216

Comment: This code can be exploited. https://drupal.org/node/2113317 http://drupalcode.org/project/context.git/commitdiff/d7b4afabb6f1aa04637b1eb724e2acf766756afb

Answer (score 0):

I ran into problems with the Services_Json extension on PHP 5.1.3, so I found the following library:

https://github.com/alexmuz/php-json

It is under LGPL, and after a very quick look does not seem to eval input.

Comment: I later found out that Services_Json was working great, the problem was that magic quotes were on on the server, which messed up the JSON strings sent by POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jsonwrapper** library...

> jsonwrapper implements the json_encode function if it is missing, and
>   leaves it alone if it is already present. So it is nicely
>   future-compatible.

Download here:
[jsonwrapper](http://www.boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html)

To use just do:

```
require ("jsonwrapper.php");


$data = array('idx1' => 'foo', 'idx2' => 'bar');

echo json_encode($data);

echo json_decode($data);
```