# Does anyone know of a simple json(p) parsing class for PHP?

Tags: php, json, oop, class, jsonp

I am stuck using a pre 5.2 release of PHP (v 5.1.6), and therefore don't have access to the handy functions like json_decode()

To complicate matters, I also don't have server privileges to install any extensions.

It would be really nice to simply include a class definition that i can use to create objects (or even a complex array) from a string of json data.

Does anyone know of a lightweight and reliable class definition that will work for me?

(I don't really feel like re-inventing the wheel here.)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This looks promising http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#80606. Most *'modern'* functions usually have backwards-compatible solutions in the comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I decode json in PHP 5.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370968/how-can-i-decode-json-in-php-5-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the pear JSON library directly and include the script in your app. Check out this link: http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON/download

Comment: Thanks Shawn. Works great when applied with examples provided by Mike B and Guillaume.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Services_JSON](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON) on PEAR, you'll use it like this:

```
if ( !function_exists('json_decode') ){
    function json_decode($content, $assoc=false){
        include_once('JSON.php');
        if ( $assoc ){
            $json = new Services_JSON(SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE);
        } else {
            $json = new Services_JSON;
        }
        return $json->decode($content);
    }
    function json_encode($content){
        include_once('JSON.php');
        $json = new Services_JSON;
        return $json->encode($content);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Zend_Json](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.basics.html), it seems OK, but I don't know the minimum php version required.