# PHP / jQuery - Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am setting an jQuery array with PHP, like this:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var postQuote = new Array();
    postQuote[<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>] = <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string(html_entity_decode($post['post_text'])); ?>
   </script>
```

My problem is, that `$post['post_text'];` can literally contain all characters. Therefore, I am getting an `unexpected identifier` error with jQuery.

My question is: how can I avoid this?

Comment: You probably need to wrap the php into quotes: `postQuote["<?php ... ?>"]`.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` is for sql, not for javascript. use `json_encode`.

Comment: @EndeNeu Just wrapping with quotes won't work if the string contains quotes, newlines, or any characters that require encoding in a JavaScript string.

Comment: @JuanMendes true that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do a `json_encode`. `json_encode` will convert your PHP variables into a variable that's usable by JavaScript. This also might remove the need to use `html_entity_decode` on most occasions, since this is not really something you should be doing to convert something that will be used by JavaScript. `mysql_real_escape_string` is not needed at all.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var postQuote = new Array();
    postQuote[<?php echo json_encode($post['post_id']); ?>] = <?php echo json_encode($post['post_text']); ?>
</script>
```

I would also set them as separate variables so that they're easier to debug and keep track of:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var postQuote = new Array();
    var postQuoteKey = <?php echo json_encode($post['post_id']); ?>;
    var postQuoteValue = <?php echo json_encode($post['post_text']); ?>;
    // See what the key and value are
    console.log(postQuoteKey);
    console.log(postQuoteValue);
    postQuote[postQuoteKey] = postQuoteValue;
</script>
```

The following example works as expected:

```
<script>
// Number
console.log(<?php echo json_encode(1); ?>); 
// String
console.log(<?php echo json_encode("hello"); ?>);
// Boolean
console.log(<?php echo json_encode(false); ?>);
// Boolean
console.log(<?php echo json_encode(true); ?>);
// Array
console.log(<?php echo json_encode(array(1,2,3)); ?>);
// Outputs a JavaScript object
console.log(<?php echo json_encode(array("a" => 345, "b" => '242', "c" => 'hello')); ?>);
</script>
```

Comment: you should use mysql_real_escape_string before inserting something into the database, it doesn't make sense at this point because it can still be manipulated at client-side

Comment: +1 It'd be good to note that if the do want to use the string in JavaScript to put HTML onto the page, they should HTML escape the content, but only when inserting it into the DOM. Encoding with JSON is definitely the easiest way to get a PHP string to play nice with a JavaScript string.

Comment: @Sepultura You should **not** use `mysql_real_escape_string`, [it's deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) You should instead use prepared statements for maximum portability, safety and speed http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: As Ende Neu said you can use single quotes like this '<?php ... ?>'

Comment: @deadman As I commented, that's a very naive fix and you should not, it'll break when the string contains new lines, quotes or any other characters that need to be escaped. Note the Ende Neu agreed.

Comment: 100% Agree with @JuanMendes. Apart from what he said, Booelans and Number don'g get passed correctly into their JavaScript counter parts

Comment: @JorgeSilva I know you know this, but just for clarity, they do if you use json_encode

Comment: Exactly! Isn't it just a beautiful, little function.

Comment: Since 5.2... but 5.2 is 8 years old. At that point, it's border line irresponsible not to upgrade! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684442/json-encode-not-working-in-php-5-1