# How to access php session data inside template files jquery code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, templates

I have ajax that calls a php file called "fetch_quarter_limit.php" from template file.

```
     $.ajax({

         type: 'POST',
         url: 'fetch_quarter_limit.php',
         data: { 
             leavefrom: from,
             leaveto: to,
             empid: emp
         },
         success: function(data) {
            var quarter_limit = data['myVar'];
            alert(quarter_limit);
         }
     });
```

In my .php file i have tried to return the session data as an array.
Fetched the required data, stored in session and formed an array.

```
$_SESSION['quarter_limit_mend'] = $quarterLimit;
$returnVal = array('myVar' => $_SESSION['quarter_limit_mend']);
echo $returnVal;
```

As shown in above ajax code part, i tried to fetch it, but all i am getting is "undefined" when i output the variable using alert.

Please help.

Ajax code updated, p2 :

Adding dataType is making code not to work.

```
$.ajax({

         type: 'POST',
         url: 'fetch_quarter_limit.php',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: { 
             leavefrom: from,
             leaveto: to,
             empid: emp
         },
         success: function(data) {
             alert(data);
    
         }
 });
```

As @Tim mentioned i have added custom json encode function to my .php file.
It returns as expected *{"myVar": 2}*

```
echo array_to_json($returnVal);
```

This is returned from php file.
But not able to access in ajax code.

Comment: You need to encode the array as JSON before you echo it

Comment: @ADyson Sorry, i didn't add that, let me try.

Comment: @ADyson php version in < 5, so json_encode is not available!

Comment: @ADyson I tried adding session_start();, but still it outputs undefined.

Comment: `php version in < 5`...then you need to upgrade urgently. You are years out of support. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php . I guess you'll have to make the JSON manually then, or find a polyfill. Echoing an array directly in PHP will just produce a warning (or nothing, if warnings are switched off, or set to log to a file) because it can't directly convert an array to a string (and even if it could, it still wouldn't be valid JSON that Javascript could read).

Comment: `I tried adding session_start()`...if you didn't add that, none of your session would work at all. Maybe it's already added in another included script or something?

Answer (score 1):

You're using echo on an array, which is not possible. As described in the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)
echo outputs one or more strings.

Usually you'd use `json_encode()` on your array and then output it to the screen. But as you've commented you are using php < 5. First of all, if possible, you should consider to  upgrade to PHP > 7, as this not only improves performance, it also improves security.

If you can't upgrade to a PHP version above PHP 5, then you can use workarounds. On this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11684471/12437108) there is already an answer for the workaround, and the [workaround](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode) can be found on the PHP manual itself.

You should be able to use the returned JSON data.

Comment: I have added the method from the discussion. `echo array_to_json($returnVal);` Passing this way. But there is no success repsonse. When i remove `dataType: 'json',` from ajax code, the alert returns as undefined. Am i missing something.

Comment: Try using console.log() on your data instead of an alert and look in the console what it returns. `console.log(data);` @Akhilpaul

Comment: In jQuery `dataType: 'json'` automatically converts JSON to an object. So to get the value of `myVar` you'd do `console.log(data.myVar)` or `alert(data.myVar)`

Comment: If the succes is not being called, then there could be an error. You can use `error: function() {}` to get the error response

Answer (score 0):

**Reply for after your edit**

So you have your data as JSON now, but JS will still see it as a string. In your success function you still have to parse it.

```
success: function(data) {
    jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(jsonData.myVar);
}
```

I do have to add too that it is very insecure to continue using php < 7.3 (as of today, 24-02-2021)