# Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_encode()

Tags: php, codeigniter, wampserver

I am using **PHP 5.1.6** and **wamp5 version 1.6.5**. It does not support `JSON` so I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_encode() in
>   C:\wamp\www\myproject\application\controllers\auth\auth.php on line
>   142

How can I solve that please help me out.

Comment: Upgrade your php version

Comment: any other solution pls

Comment: what solution without upgrade

Comment: There is this thing called google: http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/array2json/

Comment: Try install from PECL

Comment: How to install from PECL pls give me some steps

Comment: Follow the links. `boukeversteegh at gmail dot com` on http://php.net/json_encode

Comment: You should upgrade php version, if you use localhost just install new version of wamp server php 5.1.6 > 5.3 reached end of life at least use 5.4

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I encode an array to JSON without json\_encode()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431417)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I encode an array to JSON without json\_encode()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431417/how-do-i-encode-an-array-to-json-without-json-encode)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use a library as if you check the PHP.net page you will see the function is not available until v5.2.

json_encode

(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PECL json >= 1.2.0, PHP 7)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: copy the function in the link and see if that works. otherwise search for another one

Comment: SO says install via PECL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370968/how-can-i-decode-json-in-php-5-1

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you're using shared hosting or a localhost server and getting this error and you have tried installing json again with your current version of php. Then editing the php.ini (PHP Configuration File) and then trying to path json and still failed you could try the following which seemed to work for me you will need to download your current php versions php.ini file. Once you have that done edit the php.ini file and add the following to it.

;When floats & doubles are serialized store serialize_precision significant

;digits after the floating point. The default value ensures that when floats

;are decoded with unserialize, the data will remain the same.

;The value is also used for json_encode when encoding double values.

;If -1 is used, then dtoa mode 0 is used which automatically select the best

;precision.

serialize_precision=-1

Answer (score 0):

Allow json extention in your hosting in PHP Selector | extensions section.

Answer (score -2):

Create your own function. You can copy from frameworks who provides json encode or decode. One of them is `Yii`. [Available here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/ee39b8511c6c821f2e8863655d92151cc4931448/framework/web/helpers/CJSON.php#L95). However it is better to upgrade PHP. You can copy the code and do:

```
function json_encode($value) {
   return CJSON::encode($value);
}
function json_decode($value) {
   return CJSON::decode($value);
}
```

Comment: It is off topic for you to post available frameworks. OP doesn't requested a framework to use.

Comment: @Alex I am not saying the whole framework. I am forwarding to a code piece. Follow the link to see!

Comment: I think this is hectic

Comment: i am new in php. i dont know how to handle it.

Comment: @ForumUser it works without mind breaks with `PECL` which has dead.

Comment: @ForumUser what do you mean cant handle? All you need is to copy the file I have leaded you to by the link and paste the code snipped at the end. Make an include in your `index.php` and this is it.